# how do I solve ValueError in Tensorflow?

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

I am running a cnn in Google colab and i am using tensorflow or Keras. However I received this feedback

```
Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 2 for '{{node conv2d_11/Conv2D}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](Placeholder, conv2d_11/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp)' with input shapes: [?,2,2,394], [3,3,394,394].

Call arguments received:
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 2, 2, 394), dtype=float32)
```

does this have to do with my input data or my parameters? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting a number instead of using `None` when specifying the shape. As said in the documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tensor#manipulating_shapes), you run across not-fully-specified shapes when using `None`.

Answer (score 0):

in this case you have defined model which consists of MaxPool layers or AvgPool layers alot, so by the images pass through model layers, images size will be decreased; i think it would be helpful if you set `padding` parameter in convolution layer to `same` and for more details you could read about conv layers parameters `strides` and `padding`.